# change column background color according to color name in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below is my html code.Want to change column background color if we get 
        green color value in that column.  so want green background of that 
       column
        means we want change column background color according to color name.
        data will be display through web service.

Writing below html code for displaying data in html table

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Risk Category</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: How are you getting the data, via ajax or rendering page from server side ?

Comment: @FarhanTahir  Data coming through web service they are providing  color name .

Comment: @ChetanGharat and where is the color name in your question..?

Comment: You need to apply inline style in hex value like style="background-color: #000".

Answer (score 3):

Use the style inline attribute on `td` like below.

```
<td style="background-color:COLOR_NAME_OR_HASH_FROM_SERVER"></td>
```

Comment: this is static  color coding we don't know which color name  is coming from column it will be green yellow , orange anything

Comment: Yes, it would then simply be print color names and output will be like below.

`<td style="background-color:green;"></td>`
`<td style="background-color:yello;"></td>`

Comment: Let's say I'm doing it in PHP.

    `<td style="background-color:<?php echo $colorName; ?>;"></td>`

Answer (score 0):

Since you may be returning colors that don't necessarily have an interpret-able color (Amber), you may need to write some simple CSS. I just plopped it in the `<head>` for you, but you can move it to an external CSS file, especially if there's more than a few colors.

But if you can edit the markup, just add the color given by the server as a `class` on that cell.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .Amber { background: #ffbf00; }
        .Green { background: #008000; }
        .Red   { background: #f00; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Risk Category</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="Amber" colspan="1">Amber</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

If you can't edit the markup for some reason, you'll need to loop through the table cells with JavaScript and add classes that way. Something like this should get you started:

```
var cells = document.querySelectorAll('td');

for( i = 0; i < cells.length; i++ ){
  text = cells[i].innerText || cells[i].textContent;
  cells[i].className = text;
}
```

And to combine it all, here's a snippet showing how it works adding the classes with JS based on the word pulled from the server.

```js
var cells = document.querySelectorAll('td');

for( i = 0; i < cells.length; i++ ){
  text = cells[i].innerText || cells[i].textContent;
  cells[i].className = text;
}
```

```css
.Amber { background: #ffbf00; }
.Green { background: #008000; }
.Red { background: #f00; }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Risk Category</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="1">Amber</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="1">Green</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="1">Red</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```